# How to keep a log of button clicks in Android App

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have an App in which I would like to start charging the user after they use a feature 5 times.

The unpaid App allows the user to click a button (to do a pre-determined task), and after that, the user must pay to be allowed to do the same task again.

I need to make sure that the log of button clicks is saved even when the user uninstalls/then re-installs the app - this is the main thing I do not know how to do.

Please kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

first get the device unique ID with:

```
String id = Secure.getString( 
       getContext().getContentResolver(),
                   Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

then store this id on your server with number of clicks, so every time the user redownloads your app you can identify the device and check how many times the user clicked the button

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to keep this info even if the user reinstall the app, you can't save this info in local storage. You should have a database where you can store a user ID and how many times user has already clicked.

As creating a database and put it online requires some backend work, if you have no backend skills (like me), give it a try to firebase: https://firebase.google.com/

In short words, firebase is a Google solution to provide a backend to your app.

With firebase you'll be able to apply a login system (where you'll have a user ID) and create a dabatase (where you can store infos, like how many times user has used the feature)